# facebook tab app - dev account works perfectly, non-dev - login status isn't checked

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So, I have created your standard facebook test app. It has the javascript SDK loading block and the following code after it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    console.log('initiating FB');
    FB.init({
        appId:      appID,
        status:     true, // check login status
        cookie:     true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml:      true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe(
        'auth.authResponseChange',
        function(response)
        {
            console.log('authResponseChange', response);
            if (response.status === 'connected')
            {
                console.log('logged in');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('not logged in');
            }
        }
    );
};
```

The problem: with my dev account, every `console.log()` is logged, as expected. With a different account not in any way related to the app it only logs 'initiating FB', and nothing after that, even though `status: true`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Ok, found out that for some reason, it only triggers auth.statusChange event for the other account and not auth.authResponseChange. What a stupid API design, auth.statusChange and auth.authResponseChange should be merged into one to avoid this kind of bullshit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine, since there's no change in the state.

> The `auth.authResponseChanged` event is fired when the auth response has changed. The `authResponse` is part of the response object that's returned when querying the state of a person's authentication status. It contains the person's access token, when the token will expire and the person's user ID.

For an app user, when you run the app- status is changed to login since you have set `status: true`, so this event is triggered and you got `logged in` and come to the session.

But when you run the app for a not-logged-in/non-app user, this event wont trigger since the status is not changed. It was "not-logged-in" or "not-authorized" earlier and its the same now.

When you call facebook login for a not-logged-in user/non-app user, the status will change and you will see a your log as "logged in" or "not logged in".

Comment: Unnecassarily confusing API, IMHO. Especially when comparing the PHP and JS APIs. I've been fighting with this login problem for days, and only today I found out that it doesn't trigger the damn event.

Comment: You just cant write the `FB` functions anywhere, since the `FB.init` is done asynch , add your `FB.getLoginStatus` just after the FB.init is done. PS, didn't this answer helped, that you revert back?

Comment: Not really, I had figured that out before your response, I was writing the comment to my question when you responded.